# php file gets bigger when uploading

Tags: php, file, ubuntu, file-upload, server

Setup: Ubuntu Server 14.04 with PHP5 + nginx

After uploading a file through PHP which is e.g. 50KB on my harddrive, the size of the file will be about 90KB on my Server.

In my Virtual Machine with the same Setup: Ubuntu Server 14.04 with PHP5 + nginx the file will be 50KB.

What could cause this issue?